# Pandas import error (most likely due to a circular import) >>> import pandas as pd

Tags: python, pandas

When I load python (a fresh env, using conda, or similar) and try:

> import pandas

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' (most likely due to a circular import)
>>> import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case it was due to there being `csv.py` file in the current directory.